# Массив в объекте

Tags: javascript

Есть объект(JavaScript):

```
select_gender = voosel({
      title: 123,
      content: 'ololo',
      list: new array('c':'22')
})
```

list: new array('c':'22');

Нужно создать в объекте массив, в строке **list**. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так...

Comment: @Руслан Садыхов Уточните язык программирования.

Comment: Руслан, вы напишите на каком языке программирования написали этот код. Я думаю, так быстрее помогут.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите массив, то:

```
select_gender = voosel({
      title: 123,
      content: 'ololo',
      list: [ 'c', '22' ]
})
```

Если объект, то:

```
select_gender = voosel({
      title: 123,
      content: 'ololo',
      list: { 'c' : '22' }
})
```

Comment: Уточню: `['c', '22']` - массив с двумя элементами: `[0] = 'c', [1] = '22'`; {'c': '22'} - объект, со свойством `'c' = '22'`. Доступ к элементам в обоих случаях возможен как через точку, так и через квадратные скобки.

Comment: А может быть, нужен такой массив: list: [ { 'c' : '22' } ]?

Comment: Тогда можно создать объект.